# Where is my ORACLE_HOME Windows directory?

Tags: oracle, windows

I'm trying to find my `listener.ora` file to edit it, but the docs say it's in the `ORACLE_HOME` directory, but where is that?

I'm running 12.1.0 on Windows Server 2008

Comment: Windows - start the universal installer - click "Intalled Products" then the "Environment" tab.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open up a command prompt

```
Start -> Run -> "cmd.exe"
```

Start sqlplus as administrator

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

There's a system stored procedure called `get_env` for retrieving the value for `ORACLE_HOME`, thanks [Sabdar Syed](http://sabdarsyed.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-find-oraclehome-path-in-oracle.html) for the query.

```
SQL > var OHM varchar2(100);
SQL > EXEC dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', :OHM) ;
SQL > PRINT OHM
```

Should return a path like this:

> C:\app\oracle_account\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

Comment: Won't work if env var is undefined.

Comment: So `ORACLE_HOME` is actually the home of an oracle product?

Comment: `C:\app\Administrator\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1`

Answer (score 14):

On Windows platform you can find oracle_home path in the registry.

Run regedit, then navigate to:

> hkey local machine/software/oracle

Under oracle folder in the registry you will find something like:

> KEY_OraDb10g_home1

There you can see oracle_home variable.

Answer (score 1):

On cmd, type `echo %ORACLE_HOME%`. If `ORACLE_HOME` is set it will return you the path or else it will return `%ORACLE_HOME%`.

Comment: What's the default if the env var is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

- Start `regedit` (search for it from the Start menu)
- Open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder
- Open the Oracle folder
- Open a folder called ORACLEMTSR
- Open the setup folder
- Access to the current version

There you will find a "file" called HOME; open it and you will see where Oracle was installed.

Comment: At a guess, you've left out `SOFTWARE` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (on my machine, the items under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` are all generic, and there's only 6 of them - I'd expect Oracle's registry entry to be in `SOFTWARE`). Also, I suspect that `ORACLEMTSR` might actually be `ORACLEMSTR` (though I'm not sure, as I don't have an Oracle install handy to check). Could you double-check, to make sure the answer is in fact complete and correct?

Comment: Powershell single-liner: `(Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::$((Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE | Where-Object {$_.Property -eq "ORACLE_HOME"}).Name)").ORACLE_HOME`. For 32-bit Oracle client on a 64-bit Windows, `-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE` needs to be used.